# Standard project Java EE Servlets doesn't work in Intellij IDEA

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets, jakarta-ee

I generated a standard project of servlet in IntelliJ IDEA.

**Problem:**

When I open localhost:8080/javaee in the browser it works.

[image]

But when I try to open servlet page: localhost:8080/javaee/hello-servlet I  get 404 error.

[image]

**Project:**

I use Maven, here is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-ee</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>java-ee</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the structure of the project:

[image]

index.jsp has next content:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= "Hello World!" %>
</h1>
<br/>
<a href="hello-servlet">Hello Servlet</a>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloServlet.java

```
package com.example;

import java.io.*;

import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

And here is my configuration for a running of Tomcat server from Intellij Idea:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you including the `/javaee/`?

Comment: @BasilBourque I made it as the address of my application. It doesn't work even though I remove "javaee" from configuration and deploy the app on just localhost:8080

Comment: What Maven archetype did you start with?

Comment: @BasilBourque I didn't use Maven archetype. I just chose Java Enterprise in the New Project menu of Intellij Idea. Then I chose Project template - Web Application, Build System - Maven and got pom.xml above.

Comment: You are using Tomcat 9 which is aimed at the `javax.*` package naming of Java EE. But you are specifying the Jakarta Servlet 5 API in your POM, which is aimed at the `jakarata.*` package naming of Jakarta EE, and works with Tomcat 10 (not 9). Are you aware of the package-naming transition as part of the transfer of Java EE by Oracle to Jakarta EE by Eclipse Foundation? See Tomcat page: [*Which version?*](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, I know about package-naming transition, but I didn't know they weren't compatible. I'll check it now. I'll change version of servle-api

Comment: @BasilBourque THANK YOU VERY MUCH! What about Jetty 9? Is it also work only with javax?

Comment: Or, vice-versa, change from Tomcat 9 to Tomcat 10. The two products are equivalent, in parallel development during this time of transition.

Comment: Jetty is doing the same as Tomcat: two versions in parallel development, one version number for the mainstream but legacy `javax.*` package naming with Java EE, and one later version number for the cutting-edge `jakarta.*` package naming of Jakarta EE. As with Tomcat, the two versions are functionally equivalent, same features & performance. So, your choice: (a) mainstream `javax.*` with lower version number of Tomcat or Jetty, or (b) cutting-edge `jakarta.*` with higher number but functionally-equivalent version of Tomcat or Jetty.

Comment: Since your POM says you want to use Java 11, I suggest you use [Jakarta EE 9.1](https://jakarta.ee/release/9.1/) which is the same as [Jakarta EE 9.0](https://jakarta.ee/release/9/) but guaranteeing support for Java 11 beyond the previous limit of Java 8. We have all kinds of funky no-new-feature functionally-equivalent version releases during this transition time! The future Jakarta 10 will be the release aimed at new features and innovation, marking the end of this transition period.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yeah, thank you. I understood that I had a problem with versions compatibility. :-)

Comment: I am fairly certain the issue centers around your URL. I followed your steps, and got it working. The URL for me is `http://localhost:8080/jee_war_exploded/` where `jee` was my artifact name instead of your `java-ee`. Note that the URL auto-loaded in browser is controlled by `URL` field on `Open browser` section of Tomcat settings in the IntelliJ `Run/Debug Configurations` window. I will investigate more tomorrow and perhaps post more details.

Comment: @BasilBourque no, Everything is Ok :-) I changed the URL by myself on the Deployment tab and it is opened in the browser as I need. Actually, it was a problem with the version of Java EE/Jakarta/WEB Servers as you explained above.

Comment: Good. Please post and accept an Answer to the Question to help future readers, and mark this page as resolved.

Answer (score 4):

You either need to update your tomcat version to 10 or downgrade your servlet api to use `javax.servlet-api` instead of `jakarta.servlet-api` (what's specified in your current pom.xml file)

Up until tomcat version 10, tomcat supported javax as the servlet API but after tomcat 10 they only support jakarta.

Migration docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html#Migrating_from_9.0.x_to_10.0.x

Let me answer in a pseudo code cuz why not xD,

```
if (tomcat.version >= 10) 
  use jakarta.servlet-api
else 
  use javax.servlet-api
```

Comment: The issue was. the version of tomcat which was using tomcat 9. i just download tomcat 11. it works fine